# Email magic link for changing email

Tags: email, backend, user-experience

I have some hesitations to a solution we are about to build for changing emails and have a hard time finding information about it. I was hoping for some feedback from here.

The constraints are:

- The user who wants to change their email, should not get a 'email is already taken' until they have gotten the link in the new email
- We have unique emails in our system
- We do not want to switch a verified to a non verified email

For reasons, we decided to use magic links with JWT (encrypted) for verifying emails and we want to use the same idea for changing the email. The flow would look something like this:

- User will request to change their email
- Backend will send a link to the new email with email link containing an encrypted JWT token containing fromEmail, newEmail, nounce, userId (something like https://verify.something.com?token=JWT)
- User will click the link, be forwarded to a page and press the button "change my email".
- Backend will do verifications and decide if it is ok to do the email change, if all good, write to db the new email with verified = true
- JWT will have a small validity time
- The app/page will poll for changes and will give update its local state once the changes are done

I am 100% happy with going this route, because of the following:

- We have a public endpoint to change emails for users, accepting a token, the token is though signed and encrypted, but the endpoint is somewhat 'public', outside of the normal session flows that we have
- App and web flows rely on polling which adds complexity to figure out when the email is changed
- I have yet to see one provider doing this, we are deviating from the norm
- It is unknown 'UX' for the user

Is there some other disadvantages with going doing it this way?

Thanks,
Rasmus

Searched the internet for similiar solution
Looked at multiple big companies in different markets and could not find anyone doing similar